# Servlet to JSP data display

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to display my information from servlets to JSP page.

I tried many possible thing but it is coming as null.

So I wrote program which has only one parameter to display and it is also null.

JSP Page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ci1" method="get">
            User Name : <% String name1 = request.getParameter("name");
            out.print(name1); %>

        </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Web.xml:-

```
<web-app>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ci</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>control_it</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ci</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ci1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servlets:-

```
public class control_it {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
                  throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = "Display the name";
        request.setAttribute("name", name);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("try_it.jsp").forward(request, response);
   }
}
```

Comment: Servlet must be a sub-class of `HttpSevlet`. Please use proper naming conventions to name your class and other members.

Comment: Create RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("ur html");

Answer (score 0):

In your Servlet code you set an `attribute`, but in your jsp page your are trying to retrieve a `parameter`. 
Parameters are sent to the server from client side, but attributes are something completely server side.
Try to change
`User Name : <% String name1 = request.getParameter("name");out.print(name1); %>`
with this:
`User Name : <%=request.getAttribute("name")%>`

update:
servlet doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String name = "essy";
    request.setAttribute("name", name);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<h2><%=request.getAttribute("name")%></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This code and configuration works like a charm.
Give it a try.
Hope it helps

Comment: No the same ans is coming : NULL

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is backwards. You have to use the servlet first to pass the value to your JSP. Looking at your code i get the impression that you seem to think it works the other way round. Without executing the GET method from your servlet, you will not be able to access your "name" attribute.

Also, "scriptlets" (these things: <% %>) have been discouraged against since 2010.

Try this code instead:

**Your servlet (control_it):**

```
public class control_it extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public control_it () {
    super();
}

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
                  throws IOException, ServletException {

        String name = "Display the name";
        request.setAttribute("name",name);

         RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("try_it.jsp");   
         rd.forward(request,response);      
   }
}
```

**Your JSP (try_it):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ci1" method="get">
            User Name : ${name}
<input type="submit" value="GetFromServlet"/>
        </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Now you can get your value 2 ways.**

- By clicking on the button "GetFromServlet" in your form on your JSP.
- Or, by entering in the URL /ci1 in your browser search. (with your
  localdomain stuff first of course) [NOTE: this only works with **doGet**]